# Why is it initialising all the data values to 0?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    public: 
    int start;
    int end;
};

bool comp (const myclass &a,const myclass &b )
{   
    return a.start < b.start;
}
int main (void)
{
    int n,temp,t,l,r,i,j;
    cin>>t; 
    while ( t != 0 )
    {
        cin>>n;
        temp = n;
        i = 0;
        myclass arr[100000];
        while ( temp != 0 )
        {       
            cin>>l>>r;
            arr[i].start = l;
            arr[i].end = r;
            i++;
            temp--;
        }

        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
            cout<<arr[i].start<<" "<<arr[i].end<<"\n";
        cout<<"\n";
        sort(arr,arr+i,comp);
        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
            cout<<arr[i].start<<" "<<arr[i].end<<"\n";
    t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have made a class and I am trying to scan in the values in that array of myclass. But, when I print the values that I entered, it shows all 0's. 
Post the entering of the values, I have to sort the values, but the problem is that the input is not getting properly in the array of the custom class that I have made. What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: As a side note: It is considered bad practice to make members of a class public and accessing them directly. If you want to create a simple data structure with direct access to members, use `struct` instead of a class.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy Bah, it makes no difference if you use `struct` or `class` either way. `struct` has the advantage of saving some typing in this case, which is the only good reason to prefer it to `class`.

Answer (score 5):

Change `[i]` to `[j]` inside these loops:

```
for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
    cout<<arr[j].start<<" "<<arr[j].end<<"\n";
```